# Content of /proc/iomem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

1) Is it possible to access a physical address which is not defined in /proc/iomem?

2) If the physical address range of a device does not appear in /proc/iomem, does it mean that the device has not been utilized/initialized yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible to access a physical address which is not defined in /proc/iomem?

Yes.
Assuming an ARM processor which memory maps all directly-connected periperals, the driver could perform an `ioremap()` operation to map the physical memory to virtual memory for access.
But a properly written driver would first call `request_mem_region()` to ensure that it can use (and lay claim to) that physical address space.
The information in `/proc/iomem` comes from drivers calling `request_mem_region()`.

> 2) If the physical address range of a device does not appear in /proc/iomem, does it mean that the device has not been utilized/initialized yet?

You would have to inspect the driver code to determine how well written the driver is.
Is there a `request_mem_region()` before the `ioremap()`?
Check the system log using the `dmesg` command; perhaps driver initialization failed.

Assuming that this is a statically-linked driver rather than a loadable module, then as each kernel device driver has its `init()` routine called you can get trace output by having added the option "initcall_debug" on the kernel command line.  If you are using U-Boot, then this option should be added to the "bootargs" variable (which is used for the kernel command line).