# How is /proc/io* populated?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hardware

So if I understand things correctly, `cat /proc/iomem` lists the memory addresses that are mapped to this and that device register and similarily for `ioports`. If you pick up some book on Linux device drivers, it will state something about `iomem` being populated by the driver calling `request_region()` or something like that.

But how does the device driver know where the hardware register is located at from the get-go? For example, `rtc0` seems to occupy `0070:0071` for most people - how does Linux/the device driver know that the transistors and wires of my system are hooked up so that flipping exactly those bits corresponds to reading a signal from the RTC?

Comment: *"how does the device driver know where the hardware register is located"* -- It's specified by either the board or SoC designer, then conveyed in the board or SoC documentation.  The writer of the device driver then can (a) hardcode the device address (in the driver itself or a board file), or (b) retrieve it using some bus configuration method (e.g. PCI configuration space), or (c) retrieve it using a configuration list (e.g. Device Tree, ATAGs), or (d) try to probe the device at runtime.

Comment: @sawdust I'd accept that as an answer, I think it was rather exhaustive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you pick up some book on Linux device drivers, it will state something about `iomem` being populated by the driver calling `request_region()` or something like that.

The information in `/proc/iomem` comes from drivers calling **request_mem_region()**.
See [Content of /proc/iomem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580469/content-of-proc-iomem).

> how does the device driver know where the hardware register is located

The address of a device register is typically specified by either the board (for an external peripheral) or SoC designer (for an integrated peripheral), and then conveyed in the board or SoC documentation.  Some boards (e.g. PC ISA adapter boards) may allow address specification by some DIP switches.

The writer of the device driver then can
(a) hardcode the device address in the driver itself or a board file, or
(b) retrieve the device address using some bus configuration method (e.g. PCI configuration space), or
(c) retrieve the device address using a (handwritten) configuration list (e.g. Device Tree, FEX, ATAGs), or
(d) try to probe the device at runtime.

Note that conveying the system configuration and device addresses to device drivers is a longstanding issue.
The IBM PC's method of assigned addresses that were then hardcoded eventually led to the [plug and play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_and_play) initiative for x86 PCs.
Issues with unique Linux kernel builds for each and every ARM board led to the adoption of [Device Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree) (from PowerPC) for that architecture.